# Roll back Google App Engine project

Tags: google-app-engine

I was trying to deploy my App Engine app, but I got this error:

```
Error 409: --- begin server output ---
Another transaction by user <email> is already in progress for app: s~my-app, version: 1. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".
--- end server output ---
2014-08-16 18:06:15 (Process exited with code 1)
```

So I tried to solve that by running this:

```
c:\Python27\python appcfg.py rollback
```

In the directory that has my app.yaml file.

And this:

```
c:\Python27\python appcfg.py rollback <path to directory with my app.yaml file>
```

But in both cases I get this:

```
Can't open file 'appcfg.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I ended up solving it:

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine
c:\Python27\python appcfg.py rollback C:\Users\UserName\SkyDrive\Programming\ProjectFolder\app.yaml
```

Then I put in my email and passwords at the prompts, it rolled the update back, and now I'm able to deploy normally again.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd C:\path\containing\app.yaml\file
c:\Python27\python appcfg.py rollback .
```

Comment: When I try to CD to `C:\Users\UserName\SkyDrive\Programming\AppFolder\app.yaml\file` I'm told the system cannot find the path specified. Same happens when I do `C:\Users\UserName\SkyDrive\Programming\AppFolder\containing\app.yaml\file`.

Comment: I ended up figuring it out (see my answer). Thanks for the help anyway, I appreciate it.